# How to read binary data in .dat file in R? Got errors using readBin

Tags: r

I've a large .dat file (30GB), inside it is binary file as I cannot immediately see anything that makes sense when I open it using text editor. I have specific definitions about each column, should be more than 900 columns with 30,000,000 rows. All column names and values are defined as character with differing lengths. Here're the warnings I got when trying readBin function:

df = readBin(bdata, character(), n = 10)

Warning messages:
1: In readBin(bdata, character(), n = 10) :
null terminator not found: breaking string at 10000 bytes

df gave me this:

023756063201056576593012004003012008005000009844000011000000011730000012716000013583000014110000014905000015775000016965000018575000012605000012792000018083000013263000013468000020182000021175000021117000014673000014780000022961000023733000016561000015848000034450000034450000034450000034450000034450000034150000034150000034150000037386000037386000024150000024050000034050000024050000025550000035550000035550000035550000025850000025050000035050000035050000025050000025250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000311000000258000000205000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                        000004280000004353000004356000004384000004313000004000000004042000003999000004021000003991000003945000003954000003937000003979000003922000003970000003972000003957000003975000003959000004066000003939000003975000004018000004300000004300000004300000004300000004300000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

...

which is not what I should see. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look like binary data, it looks like ascii digits.  What does `readLines(bdata, 3)` give you?  My guess would be you want to use `read.fwf()`, but it's not obvious what the column widths are.

Comment: You might also want to post the first few of your 900 column definitions so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: readLines(bdata, 1) gave me:

[1] "001890848101040570628004000004004000000000000133000000176000000218000000260000000301000000342000000382000000422000000463000000500000000089000000132000000176000000218000000260000000301000000342000000382000000422000000461-00000002-00000002-00000002-.......

The first few column definitions are:

Format: Len: Start Pos: End Pos:
char 10 1 10
char 2 11 12
char 3 13 15
char 3 16 18
char 3 19 21
char 3 22 24
char 3 25 27
char 3 28 30

Sry I cannot share definitions of column names. Thanks!

Comment: The widths of the first few columns (all of them are char):

10, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3

Comment: It is ascii digits, I checked it using some function in r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would read the start of it if there were only 8 columns.  You'll need to fill in the rest given your documentation:

```
read.fwf(bdata, widths = c(10, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
         col.names = c("Col1", "Col2", ...),  # Use the actual names
         n = 3)   # Limit to reading 3 lines until you've got it right, then
                  # remove n = 3 to read the whole file
```

Comment: Problem solved! This is indeed a fixed width file, I used read.fwf and declared widths and the data file is read correctly! Thank you so much!!!!